# Initialization in the tableaux method for first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This I believe is a question that can be answered in a one-line comment, but finals are just around the corner and I want to be sure about everything.

So suppose I want to check the validity of
$$\exists x(P(x)\wedge Q(x))\models \exists xP(x)\wedge \exists xQ(x)$$
What I've been doing is to negate the implication of the two, that is
$$\neg \left( \exists x(P(x)\wedge Q(x)) \rightarrow \exists xP(x)\wedge \exists xQ(x)\right)$$
and then try to arrive to a contradiction using the rules of the tableaux method. But I've questioned myself whether this is true, that is

> $\psi \models \varphi \Leftrightarrow \psi \rightarrow \varphi$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @JeanMarie So sorry! I've edited the post accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Related post: [truth-trees-in-predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271103/truth-trees-in-predicate-logic): start  the tableau with the premise and the negation of the conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it's:

> $\psi \models \varphi \Leftrightarrow \vDash \psi \rightarrow \varphi$

But given your proof by Contradiction method, what you really use is:

> $\psi \models \varphi \Leftrightarrow \neg (\psi \rightarrow \varphi) \vDash \bot$

But yes, the method you use works just fine!